# move files to subdirectories that are named on part of the filenames

Tags: python

I have a few data files in a directory, and I want to move them to the subdirectories based on their filenames. Let's say we created the first directory named "20220322_170444," and it should contain the first four files only because in the next file the **"el"** is less than the previous one, so the second folder, let's say is "20220322_170533", then it should contain next eight files until the **el** becomes less again than the previous name.

example data

```py
files =[
'cfrad.20220322_170444.122_COW1_v2_s02_el3.40_SUR.nc',
'cfrad.20220322_170456.550_COW1_v2_s03_el4.22_SUR.nc',
'cfrad.20220322_170508.975_COW1_v2_s04_el5.09_SUR.nc',
'cfrad.20220322_170521.397_COW1_v2_s05_el5.99_SUR.nc',
'cfrad.20220322_170533.811_COW1_v2_s06_el0.45_SUR.nc',
'cfrad.20220322_170546.228_COW1_v2_s07_el1.20_SUR.nc',
'cfrad.20220322_170558.648_COW1_v2_s08_el1.90_SUR.nc',
'cfrad.20220322_170611.072_COW1_v2_s09_el2.61_SUR.nc',
'cfrad.20220322_170623.503_COW1_v2_s10_el3.40_SUR.nc',
'cfrad.20220322_170635.923_COW1_v2_s11_el4.21_SUR.nc',
'cfrad.20220322_170648.341_COW1_v2_s12_el5.09_SUR.nc',
'cfrad.20220322_170700.765_COW1_v2_s13_el5.99_SUR.nc',
'cfrad.20220322_170713.179_COW1_v2_s14_el0.45_SUR.nc',
'cfrad.20220322_170725.604_COW1_v2_s15_el1.20_SUR.nc',
'cfrad.20220322_170738.030_COW1_v2_s16_el1.90_SUR.nc',
'cfrad.20220322_170750.461_COW1_v2_s17_el2.61_SUR.nc',
'cfrad.20220322_170802.877_COW1_v2_s18_el3.40_SUR.nc',
'cfrad.20220322_170815.301_COW1_v2_s19_el4.22_SUR.nc',
'cfrad.20220322_170827.715_COW1_v2_s20_el8.01_SUR.nc',
'cfrad.20220322_170840.144_COW1_v2_s21_el11.02_SUR.nc']
```

```py
for file in files:
    np.savetxt(fname=file, X=np.array([1,1]))
```

What I tried is

```py
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import glob, os, re
import shutil

sweeps = []
temp = []
for i, file in enumerate(files[:19]):
    match_str = re.search(r'\d{4}\d{2}\d{2}_\d{2}\d{2}\d{2}', file)
    res = datetime.strptime(match_str.group(), '%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
    print(res.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"))
    el_pos = int(files[i].find('el'))
    st_pos = files[i][el_pos+1:el_pos+3]
    el_pos1 = int(files[i+1].find('el'))
    end_pos = files[i+1][el_pos1+1:el_pos1+3]
#     print(files[i][s_pos+1:s_pos+3],files[i+1][s_pos1+1:s_pos1+3])
    temp.append(files[i])
    print("len(files):",len(files),i)
    print(st_pos,end_pos)
#     print()
    if st_pos>end_pos:
        print("temp len: ", len(temp))
        sweeps.append(temp)
        temp = []
    elif len(files)-i==2:
        print('entered')
        sweeps.append(temp)
```

I now have a list named **sweeps**, and it contains the desired files; how can I now move these files to the directories,m but the directories should be named as I stated above based on the date. I have also the date string in variable **res.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")** can be used to create directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some string splitting can do this for you.

```py
import shutil
import os


files = [
    "cfrad.20220322_170444.122_COW1_v2_s02_el3.40_SUR.nc",
    "cfrad.20220322_170456.550_COW1_v2_s03_el4.22_SUR.nc",
    "cfrad.20220322_170508.975_COW1_v2_s04_el5.09_SUR.nc",
    "cfrad.20220322_170521.397_COW1_v2_s05_el5.99_SUR.nc",
    "cfrad.20220322_170533.811_COW1_v2_s06_el0.45_SUR.nc",
    "cfrad.20220322_170546.228_COW1_v2_s07_el1.20_SUR.nc",
    "cfrad.20220322_170558.648_COW1_v2_s08_el1.90_SUR.nc",
    "cfrad.20220322_170611.072_COW1_v2_s09_el2.61_SUR.nc",
    "cfrad.20220322_170623.503_COW1_v2_s10_el3.40_SUR.nc",
    "cfrad.20220322_170635.923_COW1_v2_s11_el4.21_SUR.nc",
    "cfrad.20220322_170648.341_COW1_v2_s12_el5.09_SUR.nc",
    "cfrad.20220322_170700.765_COW1_v2_s13_el5.99_SUR.nc",
    "cfrad.20220322_170713.179_COW1_v2_s14_el0.45_SUR.nc",
    "cfrad.20220322_170725.604_COW1_v2_s15_el1.20_SUR.nc",
    "cfrad.20220322_170738.030_COW1_v2_s16_el1.90_SUR.nc",
    "cfrad.20220322_170750.461_COW1_v2_s17_el2.61_SUR.nc",
    "cfrad.20220322_170802.877_COW1_v2_s18_el3.40_SUR.nc",
    "cfrad.20220322_170815.301_COW1_v2_s19_el4.22_SUR.nc",
    "cfrad.20220322_170827.715_COW1_v2_s20_el8.01_SUR.nc",
    "cfrad.20220322_170840.144_COW1_v2_s21_el11.02_SUR.nc",
]


for f in files:
    with open(f, "w") as of:
        of.write("\n")

# force the if statement below to be True on first run
el = 99999999
basepath = "."


for f in files:
    new_el = int(f.split(".")[2].split("_")[-1].replace("el", ""))
    if new_el < el:
        # store new dir name
        curr_dir = f.split(".")[1]
        print(curr_dir)
        # create directory
        os.makedirs(curr_dir, exist_ok=True)
    # store new el
    el = new_el
    # move file
    shutil.move(f"{basepath}{os.sep}{f}", f"{basepath}{os.sep}{curr_dir}{os.sep}{f}")
```

Comment: Hi @edo-akse,
Thank you for this solution. The first directory is working well, but the second directory contains all the other files, while there should have been the third one.
This is how I did it

Comment: `
el = 99999999
basepath = "."

for f in files:
    new_el = int(f.split(".")[2].split("_")[-1].replace("el", ""))
    if new_el < el:
        # store new el
        el = new_el
        # store new dir name
        curr_dir = f.split(".")[1]
        # create directory
        os.makedirs(curr_dir, exist_ok=True)
    # move file
    shutil.copy(f"{basepath}{os.sep}{f}", f"{basepath}{os.sep}{curr_dir}{os.sep}{f.split(os.sep)[-1]}")
`

Comment: ![IMG](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/syedhamidali/test_scripts/syedhamidali-patch-1/Screenshot%202022-11-29%20at%2011.40.51%20AM.png)

Comment: well color me surprised. I'm not understanding it, but testing shows you're right. The fix is weird though. See my updated answer

Comment: seems like I'm a bit of an idiot. `el = new_el` needs to be outside of the conditional. See my (again) updated answer... Please note that my current script creates the files (for testing)

Comment: Would you mind if I replace new_el line with this one new_el = `float(f.split("_")[-2].replace("el", ""))`?
I want to keep it more precise.

Comment: that would be better it seems. I didn't know that those numbers were part of the `el` as well.